# When I close the Activity the service is killed then started again

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I have a simple android program containing one activity and one service.
I am starting the service from the activity by calling: `startService()`

The service should continue running when I close my activity as I started it by calling `startService`. What I am noticing is that when I close the activity the service is killed then started again after short time.

Is that a normal behavior in android?
If it is normal, is there any way to enforce keeping the exact service running?

Thank you very much
Rami

Comment: Android may decide to kill your service at any time, and restarts them if you set the appropiate flags. You cannot change that. However, I think your case is not normal, as in theory android only kills services due to low RAM, not because your `Activity` closes.

Comment: Humm, thank you for the answer. I will check if there is something wrong, but your answer leads me to another question: can I set an action to take before that the system decide to kill my service?

Answer (score 1):

How are you "closing" the Activity? There's no need to kill an Activity once you're finished using it, and the Service should keep running even if your Activity is in the background.

Service.onDestroy() is called before the system destroys your Service. However, I am inclined to believe that you have a different problem, since it's unusual for a Service to be killed unless your device is very low on memory.